# Any way to Auto-Unzip a folder on a Chromebook?

Tags: automation, chromebook, unzip

I was wondering if there was any way to auto-extract/unzip a folder from the Chromebook download folder?  The format of the download is a .zip file from [repl.it](https://repl.it), where the format for the download of your programs is a read-only, zipped file. And to access and share it you have to copy the entire contents of the folder and move it somewhere else. Could anyone advise if it would be possible to change the folder type to Read/Write and unzip it when it is downloaded?